# Aligning the text to the center with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, anchor, responsive

```css
.lol1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.none {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.none a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="lol1">

  <div class="none"><a href="#">A</a></div>

  <div class="none"><a href="#">B</a></div>

  <div class="none"><a href="#">C</a></div>

  <div class="none"><a href="#">D</a></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Your question could be better formulated. I fixed your code. You missed to close the a tags as well. Please expain what none class is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these 3 properties to `.none`

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

`justify-content: center` will align it horicontally to the center and `align-items: center` will align it vertically.

```css
.lol1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.none {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.none a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="lol1">

  <div class="none"><a href="#">A</a></div>

  <div class="none"><a href="#">B</a></div>

  <div class="none"><a href="#">C</a></div>

  <div class="none"><a href="#">D</a></div>

</div>
```

Another solution is to put `margin: auto` on the `a` tag.
`.none` needs to be `display: flex` to work.

```css
    .lol1 {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .none {
      width: 200px;
      background-color: lightgreen;
      height: 80px;
      margin: 3px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      line-height: 1em;
      display: flex;
    }

    .none a {
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="lol1">

      <div class="none"><a href="#">A</a></div>

      <div class="none"><a href="#">B</a></div>

      <div class="none"><a href="#">C</a></div>

      <div class="none"><a href="#">D</a></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: why do i need to define the none class as a flexbox too? i already have done that with the parent class right?

Comment: @TanmayShekhar yes, but things like `justify-content` , `margin-top: auto` or `margin-bottom: auto` works on flexbox containers and `.none` doesnt have the property so you need to give it to them